# Customizing comments pagination for bootstrap

Tags: comments, twitter-bootstrap, paginate-links, comments-template, paginate-comments-links

I want to customize the comments pagination to support Bootstrap,
I have these lines in my theme file but I need more customization to display Bootstrap pagination style

```
<?php the_comments_pagination( array(
    'prev_text' => '<i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span>',
    'next_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace that snippet for this one:

```
    <?php
      $pages = paginate_comments_links(['echo' => false, 'type' => 'array']);

      if( is_array( $pages ) ) {
        $output = '';
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
          $page = "\n<li>$page</li>\n";
          if (strpos($page, ' current') !== false) 
            $page = str_replace([' current', '<li>'], ['', '<li class="active">'], $page);
          $output .= $page;
        }
        ?>
        <nav aria-label="Comment navigation">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <?=$output?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
```

This code retrieves the comments as an array, this allows to customize each one as an unordered list formatted just for Bootstrap.

It also replaces the `current` WP class for the `active` that Bootstrap uses to mark the current page.

For this code to work you also need to add the `bootstrap.css` file in your header.